# Wrap text in a list box - ms access 2010

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a list box in MS Access which retrieves results from a query. The Fourth Column contains text which is pretty long and I am wondering if I can add additional code to wrap the text in the columns.

Below is some code that loads the result set of my query in the list box

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim NbrCol As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = CurrentDb()
NbrCol = db.QueryDefs("QryRestructuringToDo").Fields.Count
Restructuring_List.RowSource = ""

Restructuring_List.ColumnCount = NbrCol
Restructuring_List.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
Restructuring_List.RowSource = "QryRestructuringToDo"
Restructuring_List.ColumnHeads = True
Restructuring_List.ColumnWidths = "1.9cm;4cm;3.25cm;15cm;2cm"

Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to force the text to *wrap* in a Listbox control.

Here is a possible workaround:  Set the scroll property to allow the user to scroll the rest of the text into view.

```
.ScrollBars = 3 'fmScrollBarsBoth
```

Here is another possible workaround: hijack the `ControlTipText` property of the form, upon user making a selection in the listbox.  It looks like this once you select an item in the list:

[image]

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
Dim i As Long
Dim str As String
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        str = ListBox1.List(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
ListBox1.ControlTipText = str
End Sub
```

Here is yet another approach, it needs some fine-tuning because it doesn't seem to be responsive once the `ControlTipText` is displayed, moving the mouse doesn't *reset* it.

Screenshot doesn't include the mouse cursor for some reason but this is how it will look:

[image]

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)


Dim rHeight As Long  'approximate the rowheight?
Dim hoveredRow As Double 'approximate the position of the cursor
Dim str As String

'Debug.Print "X: " & X & ", " & "Y: " & Y

'your mileage may vary, based on font size... this seems to work for font size 8.
rHeight = ListBox1.Font.Size * 1.25

'NOTE modular division
hoveredRow = (Y \ rHeight)
'Debug.Print "Row: " & hoveredRow

'get the text of this item in the listbox
If hoveredRow <= ListBox1.ListCount - 1 Then
    str = ListBox1.List(hoveredRow)
End If

'Display the controlTipText
ListBox1.ControlTipText = str

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks David, I will try these various suggestions. Much appreciated!